# Read file names from dropbox web page page with curl (or other) from command line

Tags: curl, dropbox

on Mac Terminal, or RPi, I would like to read & check the file names of installation files on a dropbox web page (do not want to replicate locally first).

The dropbox page has installation files for Victron - they update it regularly with new versions - want to check via command line / bash periodically if new version has been published.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/i8ru22o4ydws1rx/AADpa8lj5s2APZ2JS78OGPjKa?lst

I tried curl with several of the options, and the URL, none of them writes out the contents of above page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Dropbox API to programmatically interact with shared links.

You can use the /2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata endpoint to get information about the shared link:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata

If the shared link points to a folder, you can use /2/files/list_folder[/continue], with the `shared_link` parameter on /2/files/list_folder, to list the contents of the folder:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue

You can also use /2/sharing/get_shared_link_file to download a particular file from a shared link:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file